# How do I make a UIView act as an actionsheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

I need a view to pop up and have the user login. I can't use actionsheets for this apparently, because they only have buttons.

So I want a UIView to slide up instead.

I have created the UIView, called CustomModalView.

It seems I need some code like this:

```
- (IBAction)showTapped:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    subView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 225, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height);
    }];
    }

- (IBAction)hideTapped:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    subView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 480, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height);
    }];
    }
```

But I'm new to objective c and I don't understand how to customize this to my own project... I don't even know where to PUT this code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can take Custom UIView as per your need and then place UIButton`s on it according to your need.

Comment: what about `presetnModelVieController` instead of taking view.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using an actionsheet.
First declare a property of uiactionsheet at the interface. In below example I have declared a property named countryActionSheet.

after that in the IBaction follow the code;

```
-(IBAction)popupView{//  declare another actionSheet //
UIActionSheet *actionSheet =[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select Country"       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];

countryActionsheet=actionSheet;//equate both the actionSheets//

actionSheet.actionSheetStyle= UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
countryPicker.dataSource=self;
countryPicker.delegate=self; 

// Add your view with frame with respect to actionSheet//

UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"black background.png"];

UIButton *cancelBtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,20, 80, 30)];
[cancelBtn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];// create a method named cancelBtnPressed
[cancelBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled 4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIButton *okBtn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 80, 30)];
[okBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[okBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[okBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(okBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];// create method named okBtnPressed
[okBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled 4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[countryActionsheet addSubview:imageView];
[countryActionsheet addSubview:cancelBtn];
[countryActionsheet addSubview:okBtn];

[countryActionsheet showInView:self.view];
[countryActionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];// frame of actionSheet
}

-(void)cancelbtnPressed{
     // write action
}

-(void)okBtnPressed{
     // write action
}
```

Hope this might help you;

Comment: what is countryPicker in the above code?...@Abin George

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way is to use add view to `UIActionSheet`

```
    [actionSheeet addSubview: subView];
```

Comment: I read that you can only put buttons on an action sheet - is that not true?

Comment: no its not true. UIButton is inheritance of UIView. so if you put buttons  then also UIView.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already have had a UIViewController which a CustomModalView was added like subview. I rewrite two method above like this:

```
- (void)showLoginView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    customModalView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 225, customModalView.frame.frame.size.width, customModalView.frame.frame.size.height);
    }];
}

- (void)hideLoginView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    customModalView.frame.frame=CGRectMake(0, 480, customModalView.frame.frame.size.width, customModalView.frame.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

In UIViewController.m, call [self showLoginView] to show and otherwise

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a simple login prompt with a username and a password text input, and a login and a cancel button, you can use a `UIAlertView`. Just set its `UIAlertViewStyle` property to `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`.
If you haven't used these before, read Apple's documentation for [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) and [`UIAlertViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html).